# Smallest Unicode Box Drawing

Tags: topology

What is the smallest box diagram you can draw which uses all of the Unicode box drawing characters at least once, but without leaving any loose ends?  For reference, you must use each of these characters at least once (not counting the spaces, which are just there for alignment purposes):

```
─ │ ┌ ┐ └ ┘ ├ ┤ ┬ ┴ ┼
═ ║ ╔ ╗ ╚ ╝ ╠ ╣ ╦ ╩ ╬
    ╒ ╕ ╘ ╛ ╞ ╡ ╤ ╧ ╪
    ╓ ╖ ╙ ╜ ╟ ╢ ╥ ╨ ╫
```

By loose ends, I mean:

```
┌┐ <-Allowed  ┌┐ <-Not allowed  ┌┐┌┐ <-Allowed
└┘            └┴                └┴┴┘
```

Also, all single-lines must line up with single lines and doubles must line up with doubles, so:

```
├─, ╟─, ╠═, ╞═ <-Allowed  ├═, ╟═, ╠─, ╞─ <-Not allowed
```

You may use characters more than once each, but each character must appear at least once.  You may make multiple unconnected shapes - it is not necessary to create one single connected shape, so long as all of the ends are closed off. (But see the bonus below.)

Entries will be graded code-golf style.  Count the number of characters (including spaces, either leading or internal) used in your entry and include it in bold as a header.  Newlines are free (to prevent conflicts between 1-char and 2-char newlines on different OS's).  Then subtract 40 points (one for each of the required characters).  (A perfect score of 0 would thus use each character exactly once with no duplicates.)  Lowest score after one week wins.

**Bonus:**

Create a diagram which is one contiguous shape.  All other rules apply as previously.  If you create both a contiguous graph and a non-contiguous set of graphs, your overall score will be the average of both scores divided by two.

Comment: Those are all Unicode characters, not ASCII.

Comment: Did you mean the score would be the `average of the two` or the `average of the two divided by two`. I.E., as it is written right now, that would give @Keeta a score of `1` because (average(2,2))/2 = 1.

Comment: @EngineerToast: Honestly, I'm not sure anymore.  I thought just a straight average, but that disincentives anyone to make the contiguous one, which is why I added the divided by 2 bonus.  Always challenging to find a way to change the scoring method after first posting without screwing anyone over...

Comment: @jwodder - They were part of some "ASCII" systems.  I remember them from the old DOS days as part of IBM Extended ASCII, a.k.a. [Code Page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Code Page 437 is a _superset_ of ASCII, and the characters in it that are not from ASCII are, um, not part of ASCII. The box drawing characters are among those that are not ASCII.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Splitting hairs a little bit here, in that they were called "Extended ASCII" by at least one OS, and long before the Unicode standard existed.  The fact that they conflicted with other extended ASCII systems is part of why Unicode was invented in the first place, but the fact remains that at one time, on at least one system they were considered part of *Extended* ASCII if never part of ASCII proper.  The great thing about standards is there's so many to choose from...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: An extension of ASCII is not the same as ASCII itself. ASCII is a well-defined technical term referring to ANSI X3.4, and there is no doubt or ambiguity about which printable characters are in the character set this term names. The box-drawing characters of CP437 are _not_ in it. The quip about many standards to choose from does not change the fact that only one of those standards is ASCII. Character sets other than ASCII, even if they happen to extend ASCII, _are not ASCII_.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Score 0

Found using a small program.

$10 \times 4$ grid:

```
┌─┐╔═╗╒╦╤╕
├╥┤╟┬╢╘╣╞╛
│╠╪╬╡║╓╫┼╖
└╨┘╚╧╩╝╙┴╜
```

$ 8\times5 $ grid:

```
┌─┐╔═╗╒╕
╞╦╡║╓╨┴┘
├╫┼╢╙╥┬╖
│╟┤╠╤╬╪╣
└╜╘╩╛╚╧╝
```

Comment: Nice!  What search strategy did you use?

Comment: @2012rcampion I defined a 10*4 grid, and let the computer fill it from left to right, top to bottom, checking for each part if it fits. Primitive brute forcing would probably not work (40! possibilities).

Comment: I think we have a winner!  I had no idea it could be done without ANY duplicates.  I'm now curious if it could also be done in an 8*5 grid?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I can check it tomorrow, it's late here already. There are tons of other 10*4 solutions, so it's probable that there are also solutions for other grids.

Comment: 10*4 and 8*5 would be the only ones that fill the grid perfectly.  (A 20*2 would not work because it obviously has to be at least 3 wide in its narrowest dimension.)  I suppose with allowed white space, you could get away with a 7*6 or similar.  You'd just have to make sure the spaces are at the end of a line so they're not counted.  This made me think this would make a cool Code Golf challenge actually.  I'd set it up, but I don't know enough about those weird esoteric golfing languages to judge it fairly...

Comment: I was going to give it a week, but since you obviously can't do better than 0, I'm marking this as the winner.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Don't worry about esolangs - you can generally rely on the community to judge validity of those.  After all, no-one can be expected to know them all.  I for one tend to steer away from the esolangs, and can't really claim to know any of them.  Bottom line: if you think you have a good PPCG challenge question, go ahead and post it to [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: [Done](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/7384#7384).  Let me know if you have any suggestions for improving it.

Answer (score 18):

**Score: 2**
42 Characters, 2 duplicates - Sorry that I don't know how to format.

```
┌╥╖╓┬┐╔═╦╕
╞╬╣╠╪╡╟─╫┤ 
└╨╜╙┴┘╚═╩╛ 
╒╤╗ 
││║ 
├┼╢ 
╘╧╝
```

Bonus challenge:  **Score: 2**
42 Characters, 2 duplicates

```
╒╤╦╗╔╕╓╥╖┌┬─┐
├┼╢╟╫┤╠╬╣╞╪═╡
││║╚╩╧╝╙╨┘╘═╛
└┴╜
```

Comment: Welcome.  Nice, didn't think less than 4 was possible.  And now I see the flaw in my scoring for the bonus - might be hard to come up with a contiguous set small enough that it doesn't actually increase the score...

Comment: I guess after the latest edit (adding the contiguous diagram) I should remove the first non-contiguous set.  Maybe it makes more sense to leave it so that comments don't seem confusing.  Leaving it for now.

Answer (score 5):

### Score: 5

**Duplicates = 4, Spaces = 1**

```
╔╦╗┌┬┐╓╥╖╒╤╕╔═╕
╠╬╣├┼┤╟╫╢╞╪╡║ │
╚╩╝└┴┘╙╨╜╘╧╛╙─┘
```

### For a contiguous shape: 9

**Duplicates = 9, Spaces = 0**

```
╔╦═╗
╠╬╤╣
╟╫┼╢
╚╩╡║
┌┬┴╜
││╓╖
╘╧╝╙┐
╒╕┌╥┤
╞╪╛╙┘
├┴┐╔╗
└─┴╨╜
```

Comment: This looks pretty optimal, not sure if anyone can top that.  Maybe I should've made it more interesting and required it to be one contiguous shape instead of allowing separate ones...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You can always post that challenge as a separate question...

Comment: After edit: That IS more interesting.  Is this puzzle new enough that it would be acceptable to change the rules slightly?  I doubt there will be more submissions using the non-contiguous ones that can challenge this one, but there may be room for optimization on the contiguous one that would be cool to see...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You could edit it to have two different challenges in one. For instance, primary challenge is the original but a bonus challenge is to make a contiguous shape.

Comment: I added a bonus challenge.  It was tricky coming up with a scoring which gives an improved score for both graphs being smaller while not simultaneously screwing up anyone who only made one, but that was the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 3):

## Averaged score 6

50 characters, includes 2 spaces. I'll keep working on improvements.

**UPDATE:** 46 characters, no spaces. I suspect there's a way to deal with the triple '|' in the first figure...

```
┌╥┬┐╔╤╦╗╒╤╕╓╥╖
│║││╠╧╬╣╞╪╡╟╫╢
├╨┼┤╚═╩╝╘╧╛╙╨╜
└─┴┘
```

Contiguous: 48 characters, 0 spaces.

**UPDATE:** 46 characters, includes 1 space

```
╔╦╤╗
║╟┼╢
╠╬╧╣
╚╩╤╝
╒═╪╕
╘╦╧╛
╓╫╖
╙╫╜
┌╨┬┐
│ ╞╡
├╥┼┤
└╨┴┘
```

I know it's been solved perfectly, but I'm going to keep trying to improve my solution.